# What does DROP mean in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-drop

Was reading about 'DROP' in a SQL book I have. I am not entirely sure what it is supposed to do or means. Could anyone please give me a good description of the term?

Comment: something like `DELETE` for an object, `DROP databaseName` will drop your database.

Comment: http://www.google.fr/search?q=sql+drop

Answer (score 4):

'DROP' is sql query keyword to delete something on SQL Database

The most commonly used situation is when you try to delete Table, Database or Certain Column in a Table.

```
Delete Database
> DROP DATABASE database_name

Delete Table
> DROP TABLE table_name

Delete Column
> ALTER TABLE table_name DROP INDEX column_name
```

Answer (score 1):

DROP is a keyword in SQL which removes or deletes an element specified in the rest of the SQL statement.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_drop.asp